# How to hide certain tags in wordpress with css?

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there any way to hide certain tags in post info/meta via css ? Something like #tag-id { display:none }

Comment: Your question seems to have the answer also. Why not `tagname {display: none;}`.

Comment: That doesn't work . I have tried with tag name ,  tag id .

Comment: In that case, please post your HTML (or) create a demo so that we can see what is the issue :)

Comment: Are you using this function `get_the_tags`? If so you could do a loop with an if to check the tag id, and just return those tags you want to show.

Comment: How do I do that ? Sorry , I have no php knowledge . :(

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS may be overwritten by the theme CSS file. Try with the following css:

```
display:none !important;
```

If it doesn't work, please provide the URL of your website.

Cheers,
Dam